# CreateElement and Append two divs

Tags: javascript, html

Working with `createElement` and `appendchild` with javascript. I'm trying to work out and learn if it is possible to append divs the their classes, data etc. My current scripting sets an image in a `<li>`, I wont post the whole script (it's very long) as this is the section I believe I need help with, here is the current function:

```
function showUploadedItem (source) {

var list = document.getElementById("index-slider-list"),
li   = document.createElement("li"),
remove   = document.createElement("div"),
img  = document.createElement("img");

img.src = source;
li.appendChild(img);
list.appendChild(li);
}
```

It's end output (which I do in a php `echo ="";`:

```
<ul id="index-slider-list">// this is present before loop;
<li><img src='source-here'></li> //it starts here
</ul>
```

Let say I wanted to add two divs to this function, the first div has a class and wraps around the whole `<li>`, so I am appending `li`. The second is a div that also has a `class`, `id` and `data-toggle`, The `id` is actually php and it's syntax may cause issues:

```
<ul id="index-slider-list">
<li>
<div class='thumbnail removable'> //here is new div
<div class='remove' id='{$row['id']}' data-toggle='remove'></div> //second div 
<img src='source-here'></li>"
</div> //ends
</ul>
```

Here is where I am going (adding these two lines to the `function showUploadedItem`) but it's not working (obviously), I am also yet to work out how to post the id and data-toggle:

```
div   = document.createElement("div").className += 'thumbnail removable',
remove   = document.createElement("div").className += 'remove';

li.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(remove);
```

Is it because I am appending li two times? what would be the best approach to take here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create your elements first as a variable then add the id and classname to the variable like below.

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.id = 'myDiv';
myDiv.className = 'thumbnail removeable';

var remove = document.createElement("div");
remove.id = 'remove';
remove.className = 'remove';
```

Also, it's ok to post the full script here, it will paste in an iframe if it's really long, and will help to more easily debug to see what else is going on.